Was "The Tombs of Atuan" inspired by a real archaeology site?
I once read that the tombs in The Tombs of Atuan were based on a real archaeology site that Le Guin had visited as a child. The article did state which site it was, but I cannot find that article now or remember the name of the site. I think it was somewhere around the Mediterranean. The site was buried and possibly had its roof caved in.
Is this true? Can anyone remember the article or even the archaeology site?
[Edit: I have just seen some pictures of Malta's Hypogeum. I had a deja vu on one of the photos. Am I imagining this?]

Le Guin said that a different Earthsea story, The Daughter of Odren, had links to ancient Mycenae in Greece. Could that be what you're thinking of? I believe Atuan was actually inspired by the deserts of Oregon.

@MattThrower, do you know the site? Could it be the Malta Hypogeum I mention in the edit to my original question?

It doesn't pertain to a particular site, unfortunately: “The last story I wrote… came from idly looking at the map and wondering what life was like on O back in the old days. It turns out to have some curious resemblances to life on Mycenae.”

@MattThrower would you consider turning those comments into an answer?

@verbose possibly, but it seems very unlikely that it's the correct answer. It seems to have only the most tangential connection to what the OP is looking for: it's a different story, and it concerns a vanished civilization rather than a specific dig site.

@verbose, I think MattThrower might have a glimmer of an answer, but as he says it is a different story. I think his answer proves LeGuin may have an interest in ancient historical sites, but were the Tombs of Atuan actually inspired by a real world location?
